# DSP Algorithms Book

Tags: signal-processing

I'm looking for a book similar to "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas Cormen geared towards DSP algorithms.  Is there anything as thorough as Cormen on the DSP market?

*EDIT*
I should say I'm looking for a book that's analogous to The Joy of Cooking.

Comment: I love your cookbook analogy, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: `<The Algorithm Design Manual 2nd>` - This is a book full of fun about algorithm and math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disclaimer - I am not familiar with the Cormen book so I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

I'm a huge fan of ["A Digital Signal Processing Primer" by Ken Steiglitz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805316841).  It introduces DSP concepts like sampling, as well as simple filtering implementations, without relying just on math for explanation.  Cookbook equivalent: You know how to boil water on a stove, but you're nervous about the rest.

A more advanced book, more of a practitioner's handbook than a text, is ["Theory and Application of Digital Signal Processing" by Lawrence Rabiner and Bernard Gold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139141014).  Their explanation of the overlap-save FFT technique for convolution, in particular, is the best I've ever come across.  Cookbook equivalent: Maybe Joy of Cooking, maybe the Cordon Bleu tome.

And ["Telecommunications Breakdown" by Richard Johnson and William Sethares](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131430475) is great for taking some DSP concepts and bringing them to life by implementing a radio in software. Cookbook equivalent: A tour through a specific cuisine, and explains what "braising" is along the way.

Hope these are of use to you!

Comment: Those all look great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For theory, I like [Understanding DSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131089897) by Rick Lyons, which also has some nice "recipe-type nuggets".

More practical, and *much* more "nuggetty" is [Streamlining DSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470131578), same author.  There's some really interesting stuff in there (IMHO!).  Some of it is of the "lost knowledge" variety - especially in these days of just running Matlab's filter design functions.  Some of it relates to limited hardware machines (which is great for tiny microcontroller or FPGA implementations).

The articles are written by serious, practicing DSP engineers (many of whom hang out on news:comp.dsp) in a very accessible style.

(I'm afraid I'm no good with cooking analogies though :)

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record and benefit to others, I would recommend  [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/).

This is a good book for beginners.

Comment: @Oz and its free online!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few online books available as well at the great [DSPRelated.com](http://www.dsprelated.com):

- [INTRODUCTION TO DIGITAL FILTERS WITH AUDIO APPLICATIONS by JULIUS O. SMITH](http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/filters/)
- [MATHEMATICS OF THE DISCRETE FOURIER TRANSFORM (DFT) WITH AUDIO APPLICATIONS by JULIUS O. SMITH](http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/mdft/)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a book but I'm sure it'll be a valuable resource: The Ecole Polythechnique de Lausanne is starting a free online course on digital signal processing on February 18th 2013: https://www.coursera.org/course/dsp.

Also, the guys teaching it co-authored a book on the topic: http://www.sp4comm.org/

Answer (score 0):

A second vote for the Rick Lyons book. You might also want to get a couple of DSP "bibles", e.g. [Oppenheim & Schafer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132146355) and [Proakis & Manolakis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873741), which are more theoretical but cover more ground.

Comment: Rick Lyons wrote two books about DSP : http://www.amazon.com/Richard-G.-Lyons/e/B001IQX764/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, the first book, "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" (now in third edition I see) is the main one, although "Streamlining Digital Signal Processing" looks useful too.

Answer (score 0):

The DSP handbook: algorithms, applications and design techniques - Bateman, Andrew, Paterson-Stephens, Iain 2002

and

Introduction to digital signal processing - Meddins, Bob 2000

Have basically made my ADSP module a breeze (so far). They are also at the top of the suggested reading list. As such, both are fairly beginner friendly, and the latter includes Matlab examples.

The former is probably more Delia, while the latter is more 'my first cook book'.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add Vetterli, Kovacevic, and Goya's [Foundations of Signal Processing](http://fourierandwavelets.org/), which can be downloaded for free.