# signal processing for a web programmer

Tags: computer-science, signal-processing

What books would you recommend to a CS undergraduate that did mostly web programming all his life, in order to pick up signal processing ?
I am looking for something at a grad level and more geared toward an average (or below average) programmer.

Comment: Do you want to get through an elementary DSP course, or do a simple project? In any case, DSP has nothing to do with web programming or structured programming/computer science in general. It's essentially pure, continuous-domain math, with discretization and quantization to make it amenable to computers. Filters can be interfaced to complex programs, but then you probably want to treat them as black boxes.

Comment: I've already got through an elementary DSP course, now I am taking the advanced one, but since I didn't pay too much attention to the first one, I'd like to start with something fresh and see how things relate with what I am doing on a daily basis.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823975/dsp-algorithms-book

Answer (score 4):

If you want a free DSP book, check out [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://dspguide.com/) by Steven W. Smith, Ph.D. I found it handy when I was interning at a national laboratory some years back and was asked to program a DSP chip to do some lock-in amplifying when I had no previous DSP experience (or books available to me on the subject).

Answer (score 2):

I found
[Ken Steiglitz "A Digital Signal Processing Primer: With Applications to Digital Audio and Computer Music"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805316841)
one of the most accessible books on the subject (after trying a few of the 'classics'), he explains all needed math well (you do need to know some calculus though, its inevitable, but less than some other books imho). And really tries to give you a feeling/intuition for everything through lots of examples in digital audio (the field I was interested most).

For me it was one of the hardest things to learn through selfstudy I tried so far, but it gives great satisfaction and many "aha!" moments ;)

Comment: I wonder if he's related to Alfred Steiglitz (the famous photographer)

Answer (score 1):

I have found this one : 
[http://www.amazon.com/Signal-Processing-First-James-McClellan/dp/0130909998/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1276906982&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130909998)
Very easy to understand and very complete.
Don't get frightened by the cover with all those kitties ( well, I prefer that to those ants on Deitel)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most accessible book with reasonable depth is Rick Lyons's [Understanding Digital Signal Processing](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Digital-Signal-Processing-Richard/dp/0131089897).

Answer (score 0):

This is a new release: [Digital Signal Processing 101: Everything you need to know to get started](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/bookdescription.cws_home/722691/description#description), the synopsis suggests it may be what you are looking for.  You may want to wait for a review or extract publication if you cannot afford to buy it in spec.